# insert an xml payload into a column as it is

Tags: sql, xml

I want to insert the following xml payload into a table column.

```
<PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
  <AuctionBidsResponse>
    <AuctionBidOutput>
      <BidOfferRef>-1</BidOfferRef>
      <Reason>xxx : Provider/Auction/Customer is not valid'</Reason>
      <Provider>HGM</Provider>
    </AuctionBidOutput>
  </AuctionBidsResponse>
</PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
```

when I try to insert this, I was forced to convert this into a varchar value. but when I convert this, the value in the table looks like following.

```
<PostTransAuctionBidsResponse><AuctionBidsResponse><AuctionBidOutput><BidOfferRef>-1</BidOfferRef><Reason>xxx : Provider/Auction/Customer is not valid'</Reason><Provider>HGM</Provider></AuctionBidOutput></AuctionBidsResponse></PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
```

is it possible to change this to look like the above payload?

what I am doing is something like-

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = 
'
    <PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
      <AuctionBidsResponse>
        <AuctionBidOutput>
          <BidOfferRef>-1</BidOfferRef>
          <Reason>xxx : Provider/Auction/Customer is not valid'</Reason>
          <Provider>HGM</Provider>
        </AuctionBidOutput>
      </AuctionBidsResponse>
    </PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
' 

declare @Content varchar(max)
set @Content = convert(varchar(max),@xml)

insert into TES_Log(content)
values(@Content)
```

Comment: What kind of database? Code sample of how you do it?

Comment: So - is it Microsoft SqlServer ?

Comment: Best to tag it so, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article ([link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/converting-string-data-to-xml-and-xml-to-string-data/)) you need to explicitly convert also when assigning the value to your @xml variable. And in both cases you also need to include the third argument to convert():

```
set @xml = convert(XML,
'
<PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
  <AuctionBidsResponse>
    <AuctionBidOutput>
      <BidOfferRef>-1</BidOfferRef>
      <Reason>xxx : Provider/Auction/Customer is not valid'</Reason>
      <Provider>HGM</Provider>
    </AuctionBidOutput>
  </AuctionBidsResponse>
</PostTransAuctionBidsResponse>
', 1)

set @Content = convert(varchar(max),@xml, 1)
```